# Fast algorithm for counting intersection of sorted arrays with cyclic shift

Tags: arrays, algorithm, rust

I'm looking for a faster algorithm that solves the following problem:

- Input: Two arrays of integers `A` and `B` in the range `[0, N)`, both of fixed length `d`, assumed to be given in sorted order with no repeated elements.
- Output: Whether the largest possible intersection (i.e. number of elements in common) between `A` and a cyclic shift of `B` is greater than some specified threshold `t`. By a cyclic shift of `B`, I mean the array `[(b + s) % N for b in B]` for some integer `s`.

If it matters, I'm implementing this in Rust (though I'm more interested in general algorithmic improvements than language-specific optimizations), and in practice, `t` will be less than 10, `d` will typically be in the range of 15 to 150, and `N` will be roughly on the order of `2*d*d`.

My current algorithm is essentially as follows (note, `d` and `N` are constants defined at compile-time):

```rust
fn max_shifted_overlap_geq(A: [u32; d], B: [u32; d], threshold: u32) -> bool {
    for i in 0..d {
        for j in 0..d {
            let s = N + A[i] - B[j];
            let mut B_s = [0; d];
            for k in 0..d {
                B_s[k] = (B[k] + s) % N;
            }
            B_s.sort();
            // Actually, I do an insertion-sort in place as I construct B_s,
            // but I'm writing it this way here for simplicity.
            if sorted_intersection_count(&A, &B_s) >= threshold {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    false
}
```

So I'm only choosing shifts from the possible values of `A[i] - B[j]` (since a shift not of this form gives zero intersection), and then I just construct the cyclic shift of `B` and count the number of elements in common in a fairly naive way.

Is there a more efficient algorithm for this, keeping in mind the fairly small size of the arrays? In particular, is there a better way of finding shifts that are more likely to yield large overlaps?

Edit: To provide additional context (as requested below), this arises in the study of QC-MDPC codes: The arrays represent the supports of binary vectors that generate the circulant blocks of the parity-check matrix, and this condition on the intersection with cyclic shifts defines a class of "weak keys" with some cryptographic implications. (I initially didn't mention this because the problem seems interesting in isolation and doesn't require any knowledge of coding theory or cryptography.)

Edit 2: Fixed some typos in the code and switched to a better method of counting intersections of sorted lists. (Weirdly, I actually had used that improved algorithm in an earlier version and the code ran slower, but that might've been due to an implementation bug or now-fixed problems elsewhere in the code.)

Edit 3: For future reference of anyone who runs into a similar problem, here's my current implementation, using the key idea from virchau13's answer below plus some small additional optimizations. This seems quite efficient in practice. (I've renamed some variables for clarity—`arr1` and `arr2` for the input arrays, and `LEN` instead of `d` for the array length.)

```rust
fn relative_shifts(arr1: &[u32; LEN], arr2: &[u32; LEN]) -> [[u32; LEN]; LEN] {
    let n = N as u32;
    let mut shifts = [[0; LEN]; LEN];
    for i in 0..LEN {
        for j in 0..LEN {
            shifts[i][j] = if arr1[i] < arr2[j] {
                n + arr1[i] - arr2[j]
            } else {
                arr1[i] - arr2[j]
            }; // this equals (arr1[i] - arr2[j]) % n
        }
    }
    shifts
}
fn max_shifted_overlap_geq(arr1: &[u32; LEN], arr2: &[u32; LEN], threshold: u8) -> bool {
    let shifts = relative_shifts(arr1, arr2);
    let mut shift_counts = [0; N];
    for i in 0..LEN {
        for j in 0..LEN {
            let count = &mut shift_counts[shifts[i][j] as usize];
            *count += 1;
            if *count >= threshold {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    false
}
```

A couple implementation notes:

1. This could easily be modified to produce the largest possible intersection as a value (by taking a maximum instead of short-circuiting when the threshold is exceeded) or a set of index pairs (by also appending the index pairs `(i, j)` to a list associated to each shift `s` as it's computed).
2. We do not need to assume the arrays are sorted for this to work. For that matter, I don't think we need to assume the arrays are of the same length, either, though I haven't tested this for arrays of different lengths.

Comment: It's an interesting problem. I wouldn't mind seeing another sentence or two that motivates it from some real-life context. In particular, I am not yet grasping the significance of the (pretty small!) threshold `t`. The mod `s` aspect is intriguing, I view it as similar to the moiré pattern you get from moving two silk layers against each other. Can't say I'm excited about O(d^3). It feels like the _differences_ in successive A elements, and B elements, is what we should be processing, since they are invariant when `s` changes. Sorry, not seeing an algorithm for that, yet.

Comment: I think your code is incorrect? The `B_s` calculation is unnecessary, since it's never used to compute `weight`.

Comment: @virchau13 there are a few things wrong with his current implementation, like assuming `A[i]` is always greater than `B[j]`.

Comment: @J_H actually what he has here is `O(d^4)` because of the intersection counting double loop. Here is a faster (`O(N)` versus `O(N^2)`) algorithm for computing the intersection count of two sorted arrays:  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1f31ee3e3c3d04e43eacf814ed415e7a

Comment: @virchau13 That's a typo, `B.contains` should be `B_s.contains`. And yes, I think it's `O(d^4)`.

Comment: also the issue with `A[i]` possibly being smaller than `B[j]` can be fixed by replacing with `N + A[i] - B[j]` since it's all mod `N` anyway. Sorry, I introduced a couple typos like this in the process of translating from my existing code; I hope the gist of the algorithm is clear enough regardless.

Comment: Please edit your question with the fixes. Ideally you would provide a working [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) with some tests as well.

Comment: How large are the values in `A` and `B`? Does they really inhabit the full `usize` space? BTW, you should not use `usize` as a generic integer type in Rust. Choose one of the sized integers, like `u64`.

Comment: @PitaJ Thanks for the suggestion of a faster intersection counting algorithm. The values in `A` and `B` are in the range `[0, N)`, where `N` is typically around `2*d*d`, so a `u32` or maybe even a `u16` would suffice. There are some reasons elsewhere in the code why I chose `usize` but probably I should refactor a bit to avoid that.

Comment: In that case, the cyclic shift essentially "rotates" the starting index of the sort of your array, with the new minimum being at `B[j]`. I think you can use that to avoid needing to sort `B_s` at all. `B_s[0] = (B[j] + s) % N`, `B_s[d-1] = (B[j-1] + s) % N`, etc

Comment: To avoid re-checking repeated differences, you could store what `s` you've already checked in a `HashSet` or something. It should only need `d^2` memory.

Comment: I already tried using a `HashSet` for the list of shifts; even with a fast hashing function it's slower, presumably because the overhead outweighs skipping the occasional repeat.

Comment: What did you try with the `HashSet`? Did you use `with_capacity` to pre-allocate memory? You could try a `[bool; N]` array instead.

Comment: @DanielHast If you transform the array from absolute values to differences between two consecutive elements, you get the 'cyclic transform' for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's possible to get the algorithm down to O(d^2). This is just (untested) speculation.

For two elements `A[i]` and `B[j]` to be cyclically equal, `(B[j] + s) % N` must equal `A[i]`. If `s = s_orig` satisfies this equation, then `s = s_orig % n` also satisfies this equation, meaning that we can restrict `s` to `0 <= s < N`. Using this restriction, we can show that two elements are cyclically equal if and only if `B[j] + s` equals either `A[i]` or `A[i] + N` (since `0 <= A[i],B[i] < N`), which is the same as saying that `s` must equal either `A[i] - B[j]` or `N + A[i] - B[j]`. However, since `0 <= s < N`, the first term only makes sense when the difference is positive or zero and the second term only makes sense when the difference is negative; i.e. we can say that `s` must equal the expression `if A[i] - B[j] < 0 { N + A[i] - B[j] } else { A[i] - B[j] }`. Another way to write this is `s = (N + A[i] - B[j]) % N`.

Note that since there is exactly one value of `s` for each `(i,j)` pair, two `(i1,j1)` and `(i2,j2)` pairs both overlap if and only if the values for `s` for each of them are the same.

So here's the final algorithm:

1. Start by enumerating all possible `s` cyclic differences between `A` and `B` and put them in a 2D array: `possible_values: [[usize; d]; d]` `possible_values[i][j] = (N + A[i] - B[j]) % N`. This is O(d^2).
2. Next, find all unique `s` values (i.e. unique values of `possible_values[i][j]`) and store the list of indexes each `s` value has in a hashmap `unique_possible_values: HashMap<usize, Vec<(usize, usize)>>`. That sentence isn't very clear so here's what I mean:

```rust
let unique_possible_values: HashMap<usize, Vec<(usize, usize)>> = HashMap::new();
for i in 0..d {
    for j in 0..d {
        let indexes_with_same_value = 
            unique_possible_values
                .entry(possible_values[i][j])
                .or_insert(Vec::new());
        indexes_with_same_value.push((i, j));
    }
}
```

In other words, each entry of the hashmap stores the list of 2D indexes `(i,j)` that share the same `possible_values[i][j]` value. This is O(d^2).

3. Then, for each unique `s` value (`for (s, indexes) in &unique_possible_values`), count the amount of cyclically equal elements it has. This is equal to the number of unique `i`-values and the number of unique `j`-values, which can be computed in `O(indexes.len())` time. I'm not going to write the code out for this, but it shouldn't be difficult, and it's O(d^2) (since each 2D index you iterate over occurs exactly once).
4. Take the maximum of all the counts from step 3. This is worst-case O(d^2) and average case significantly lower. This final value corresponds to the maximum possible size of the A and B cyclical intersection.
5. Check if that value exceeds `threshold`. If it does, return true; otherwise, return false.

This algorithm basically enumerates all possible `s`-values and calculates the max intersection length, but in a efficient manner.

Comment: Wow, this is great, the idea to associate the shifts to an index pair is just what I was missing! I think step 3 is actually trivial: the shifted intersection size is just `indexes.len()`. Also, I found that in practice, building the `HashMap` is too slow (even using `nohash-hasher` and `with_capacity`) and it's much faster to just implement it as a length-`N` array of integers that counts index pairs with a given shift. I'll leave the question open for a little longer just in case someone comes up with an even more efficient algorithm, but I wouldn't be surprised if this is near-optimal.

Comment: Can't you avoid step 4 by computing the maximum as you're iterating in step 3?

Comment: @PitaJ I do that in my actual implementation. I also skip step 5 by immediately returning upon finding a value that exceeds the threshold. But these are small optimizations compared to the huge difference switching to the `O(d^2)` algorithm makes.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert each input array into a new vector of length N, with a 1 for values that occur in and a 0 for other values.

Then calculate the cyclic cross correlation between the two vectors, and find the highest value -- that's the size of the maximum intersection.

The time is dominated by the correlation calculation, which takes O(N log N) time using FFT techniques.  That is better than d<sup>3</sup>, but it's pretty complicated, so whether it's going to be faster will probably depend on whether or not N is a power of 2 and the specific implementation.  If you have a GPU available for the FFT then it can be much faster.

Comment: Thanks! This isn't of immediate use to me anymore since the other answer is O(d^2), but I didn't realize it's fast to compute cyclic cross correlation of binary vectors, and maybe this will be useful for other things I'm doing. Do you know of a good reference for further reading on how to use FFT for this?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but a google search for "fft correlation" yields many relevant results.  "fft convolution" (which is the same thing, with one array reversed) yields even more.  The technique is used all over the place, and works for a lot more than just binary vectors.